# Heroku Nodejs Server img file keep getting 404

Tags: html, css, heroku, github, http-status-code-404

```
background: url('img/edu2.jpg') center center no-repeat scroll;
```

This image is working fine in localhost. When I deploy it to Github and Heroku automatically deploys it. However, Heroku keeps showing me that it cannot GET this image, and server responded with a status of 404.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome (similar in other browsers): Right-Click on the image, Inspect. Under the elements tab, you can see on the right frame (Styles) all the CSS styles. Scroll down to the `background` and check what image path it actually takes (absolute address). You can see the absolute address by hovering over the relative one (or right click, open in new tab). Then, check if this is correct (what it is obviously not).

The problem is, that `img/edu2.jpg` is relative to the path of the HTML file. If you add a `/` to the beginning, it will take the root of the website as its relative base.

Comment: I added a / to the beginning, and it still doesn't work. I followed your procedure, and it still shows me this blank page with a message "Cannot GET /img/edu2.jpg". And the URL for that blank page is "https://mark-wen-home.herokuapp.com/img/edu2.jpg "

Comment: What is the correct path to your image (absolute)? You need to adapt the relative URL, so that it links to the correct absolute URL. The ``/`` in the beginning of the relative URL makes it only relative to the root path. If this is not the correct link, then it obviously does not work.

Comment: It is relative I think. And it is only this specific image not working, others that are in the same folder are working fine

Comment: How does the relative path differ from this image to the other (also in CSS background defined) images? Do they also look like ``url('img/filename.jpg')``?

Answer (score 1):

This very well may be an issue of relative paths. The first step is to discover what URL your browser is trying to fetch the resource at by looking at the console in your browser's developer tools. It would be very helpful if you linked the website that's facing this error as well as the source code behind it so that it's possible for outsiders to debug it.